# Setting the type of cursor on a ToolStripStatusLabel object

Tags: c#, winforms, toolstripstatuslabel

I have a `StatusStrip` object at the bottom of my form with a `ToolStripStatusLabel` object added to it.  I want to change the type of mouse cursor that is displayed when one hovers over it.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Use its MouseEnter and MouseLeave event.  Change the Cursor property of the StatusStrip in your event handlers.

Comment: That's just it.  When I click on the `StatusStrip` and look at properties I do not see any property such as `Cursor`

Comment: Of the **StatusStrip**, not the label.  It requires code.

Comment: Ahh ok got it!  I was not aware that it just was not exposed in the `StatusStrip` properties during design-time.  Thanks Hans.  Also, can you add that as an answer please?  You are notorious for answering in a comment and not an actual answer.  :P - You probably do it so that you don't get a million notifications.  :)

Comment: You have everything you need to know to answer the question yourself.

Comment: Have you ever tried using `ToolStripControlHost` to host a `LinkLabel` or other controls in a `ToolStrip` or `StatusStrip`? It's really a good option.

Comment: @ArvoBowen Hosting a `Label` or `LinkLabel` in a `ToolStripControlHost` is really a useful option which allows you to set the cursor or other properties. In fact I believe it's really more effective than handling mouse events and changing the cursor.

Comment: Would you mind your actual requirement? What cursor do you need? Do you set `IsLink` property to true?

Comment: @RezaAghaei Your answer that gave an additional method that you deleted was a nice answer and great extra info but a lot more than what I was asking for.  The simplest and correct answer is the one I provided below based off of Hans comment.  The only reason it's not checked yet is because of stackoverflow's restrictions on how long I have to wait to mark it as the answer.  You should add your answer back for possible upvotes in the future.  Thanks

Comment: Thank you for your response :) I liked your post and maybe your post is the best fit for the question. But the ability to adding a normal `Label` to the strip is also a good alternative and it's just 2 lines of code.

Comment: By the way, while you can accept only one answer, you can upvote as many answers as you find useful.  Did you know it? In fact, upvotes are for saying that an answer is useful. It makes the answers more useful for future readers. Also it motivates users to post good answers :)

Comment: Yea, and I was going to upvote yours as soon as I could accept mine.  ~14 hours ;)

Comment: OK, I'll undelete it. Hope it helps you and future readers :)

Comment: What a forgotten question and answers ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ToolStripStatusLabel` object does not have a `Cursor` property.  In order to change the displayed cursor you must set the `StatusStrip.Cursor` property at run-time.

Use the label's MouseEnter and MouseLeave event to change the StatusStrip.Cursor property.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you can host a `Label` in [`ToolStripControlHost`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripcontrolhost(v=vs.110).aspx) and add it to `StatusStrip`. This way you can set all `Label` properties including `Cursor`. It will act like other standard items.

```
var item = new ToolStripControlHost(new Label {Text= "Some Text", Cursor= Cursors.Hand});
this.statusStrip1.Items.Add(item);
```